# a basic question: where can I add css code to change colors for the "plugin for Google Reviews" By RichPlugins for Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I am new in Wordpress and I have the website with elementor just finished. Now I just added the Plugin for Goolge Reviews by RichPlugins and I want to change the colors of the background and so on. I have found the css code but my question is, where do I exactly have to add this code?

To style.css?

thanks in advance!

I haven't tried nothing yet

Comment: Doesn't the `Appearance > Customizer` menu offer an option to add custom CSS globally, all the way at the bottom of the menu on the left?

Comment: If you really want to add it to an actual CSS file, it should be in your theme directory somewhere, within `wp-content > themes > [theme-name]`. Its exact location depends on the theme you're using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, editing `style.css` is one, valid option. It's good to edit that file if you know you have a lot you want to change your site.

If you only want to do small CSS changes, `Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS` is a good pick.